# Azure DevOps API Test results

Tags: c#, .net, azure, api, azure-devops

I am new to azure DevOps and trying to get all test Results in C# for a project. So far it worked with workItems, does anyone know how it can be done with test results

I followed this :

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples

Answer (score 1):

To get all the test results in your project, you can try like as below:

1. Use the REST API "[**Runs - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to list all the test runs in the specified project on Azure DevOps.
2. Use the RESI API "[**Results - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" in a loop to list all the test results for in each test run.